# Add buttons Dynamically as rows and columns on android?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int i,j;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                Button myButton = new Button(this);
                myButton.setText(""+j);
                myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                myButton.setTextSize(20);
                layout.addView(myButton);                   
        }
                    layout1.addView(layout);
                    for(j=5;j<10;j++){
                        Button myButton = new Button(this);
                        myButton.setText(""+j);
                        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        myButton.setTextSize(20);
                        layout2.addView(myButton);                      
                }
                    layout1.addView(layout2);

        setContentView(layout1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above is my code. I am able to dynamically create two rows of button with 5 columns. But here I have to manually create layouts for rows(layout,layout2). I thought I will define a linearlayout array. But when I try too specify the setOrientation and setLayoutParams the program crashes.
I tried

```
layout3[0].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

But program crashes.

Comment: What do you mean by `program crashes.`? Does it throws any exception something in logcat maybe?

Comment: I am a newBie to this field. What I meant by crash was that whenever I try to run the program. It displays that error in the black box saying "Program stopped working unexpectedly". I checked the logcat it has something like android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: Thats all right. +1 that you got answer to your problem. Next time please add Exception, it tell lot of information about where and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually simple

You need to specify

```
layout3[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout3[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout3[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Then it works.